# Format datetime in where condition in EasyQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Mine is a MVC application having easyquery widget.

I need to format datetime columns in where condition like '2013-05-06 12:20:35'.

But when I tried

```
dbQuery.Formats.DateTimeFormat = "'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'";
```

It is simply omitting single quotes and giving me like 2013-05-06 12:20:35. 
If I am replacing single quotes with # like

```
dbQuery.Formats.DateTimeFormat = "#yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss#";
```

It is getting reflected like #2013-05-06 12:20:35#.

How to format this?

Comment: try dbQuery.Formats.DateTimeFormat = "\'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\'";

Comment: No.. That wont do the trick..:(..single quotes getting omitted

Comment: dbQuery.Formats.QuoteTime = true;
And remove those quotes from DateTimeFormat property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query.Formats.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"; 
query.Formats.QuoteTime = True;
```

Found from [here](http://devtools.korzh.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=879)

Comment: It's better to use:

`query.Formats.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";`

hh - is for 12-hour clock format. To make 24-hour use HH